# Safari gets 404 on mp4 from IIS

Tags: iis, safari, html5-video, mp4, video.js

I'm using IIS to serve mp4 videos. I get a 404 on mac/safari. It works in chrome and firefox on the same macs. The MIME is video/mp4 .

I've ran tests locally to rule out the video encoding, and the videojs. I've taken the request path directly as well, skipping the html and js, with the same results. Safari will not load the direct  url to the video either.

I'm not sure where to look next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Safari does range requests for media. IIS itself can handle this, but we are using mvc routing - and we didn't provide any handling for this. The solution is to build an action result that handles range request. We're pulling a solution based on [this article](http://tpeczek.blogspot.com/2011/10/range-requests-in-aspnet-mvc.html)